# Required tag in select field doesn't work

Tags: php, html, html-select

I try to add the required attribute to my select tag. Unfortunately this is simply ignored. The drop down list is filled dynamically from database entries. Does anyone know why? Is the dynamic elements to blame?

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
    <?php
    //-------------------------------------------//
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM availableCards WHERE Active = '1' ORDER BY Description");
    $statement->execute();
    echo '<select name="images" id="images" required>';
    echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Bitte wählen</option>';
    while ($data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            echo '<option name="' . $row['Value'] . '" value="' . $row['Value'] . '" data-icon="../cards/' . $row['ImagePath'] . '">' . $row['Description'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
    //-------------------------------------------//
    ?>
    <label for="images">Karte auswählen</label>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `submit button` and `form tag`

Comment: are you using any 3rd party library like select2?

Comment: look here example [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required)

Comment: @BhargavChudasama I didn't put the whole thing in here. It's just too big. Right next to the drop down list is a inputfield, which works fine with the required tag.

Comment: Are you properly using html5 for the required attribute on a select tag?

Comment: @Exception No, nothing like that.

Comment: I've tested you code locally and it works fine. It won't allow me to progress unless selected. I added the form tag and a button though.

Comment: @Adrian can you just post your final HTML in https://pastebin.com/ and put link here.

Comment: @Exception Here you go https://pastebin.com/sG8uBF09

Comment: I said HTML and not a code.. go to your web page and right click at it and click on view source and then paste that code in pastebin.com

Comment: @Exception Oops, sorry my bad! https://pastebin.com/Gm88Qapu

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the below block. It's possible the form you have is not nested correctly.

```
<form action="/">
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
    <?php
    $data = array(
        '1' => 'One',
        '2' => 'Two',
        '3' => 'Three',
    );
    //-------------------------------------------//

    echo '<select name="images" id="images" required>';
    echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Bitte wählen</option>';
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo '<option name="' . $row['Value'] . '" value="' . $row['Value'] . '" data-icon="../cards/' . $row['ImagePath'] . '">' . $row['Description'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    //-------------------------------------------//
    ?>
    <label for="images">Karte auswählen</label>
    <button type="submit" name="button">Bestätigen</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Please add the closing form tag and the of the last div. StackOverflow's embed code is a nightmare.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.. sadly. Next to the select tag is an inputfield which work just fine. The form and everything seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what happening is at your HTML value="" is not printing in

```
<option disabled selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
```

But in your code you have already added

```
echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Bitte wählen</option>';
```

If you just focus on that why it is not showing `value=""` in option tag then it will work fine.

Comment: Now it's showing value="" in the HTML. Unfortunaly it is still not working.

Comment: if still not working at your end then keep looking at console of the browser and see if any error is there related to your field OR jquery

Comment: and also clear all your browser cache just to make sure page loaded is not cached

Comment: Okei i just got an error: An invalid form control with name='images' is not focusable.